# How to align label into top of this input form

Tags: html, css, forms, web-applications, responsive

I"ve created a dummy registration form in HTML and added some CSS
and the label tag which i used is aligned to the left corresponding to the input
and
I want to align this label into top of the input form when the width is
like this

```
@media (max-width:520px)
```

to make this responsive

I've tried display block but it does not work

[like this when width is below 520px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9teI.png)

Here's the Code

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>This</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style4.css" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"/>

  <body>
    <div id="fmr">
      <div class="titl">Registration Form</div>
      <form action="info.php">
        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>First Name : </label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>Last name : </label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label> Email Address : </label>
          <input type="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>Gender : </label>
          <div class="slgn">
            <select name="gender" id="gender">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label for="idc"> Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="tel" pattern="[+]{0-2}{0-12}" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label for="ide"> Address : </label>
          <textarea class="address"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input_sl">
          <label class="chckbx">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check"></i>

            <span class="ttbx"> Do you agree to the terms and conditions </span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: TitilliumWeb,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
    background-color: rgb(149, 101, 82);
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.titl{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
}

#fmr{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 3px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.704);
    background-color: rgb(181, 175, 169);
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.input_fld{
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.input_fld > label{
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.slgn{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vh;
}

.slgn select{
    appearance:none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d5dbd9;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
.slgn:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 10px;
    border: 8px solid;
    border-color: #d5dbd9 transparent transparent ;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
.slgn select:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    animation: 0.8s ease;
  }

input[type="text"] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    height: 6vh;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    animation: 0.8s ease;
}
input[type="tel"] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

input[type="email"]{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 6vh;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.input_fld textarea{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 88px;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding:10px 13px;
}

.input_fld textarea:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}
 
input[type="checkbox"], .chckbx .fa-square-check {
    display: none;
}

.fa-square{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .fa-square-check {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .fa-square {
    display: none;
}

.chckbx i:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

i {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.ttbx{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18.8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 74px;
}

.input_fld .btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 11px;
    font-size: 19px; 
    border: 0px;
    background:  #6b8669;
    color: #343533;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 10px 0 auto;
  }

.input_fld:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  @media (max-width:520px) {
    .fmr form .input_fld{
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
    .fmr .input_fld label{
      display: block;
    }
    .fmr form .input_fld{
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see

[image]You can access the id via #element_id.

```
 @media (max-width:520px) {
#fmr form .input_fld{
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

}

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: TitilliumWeb,sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


body{
    background-color: rgb(149, 101, 82);
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.titl{
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
}

#fmr{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 3px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.704);
    background-color: rgb(181, 175, 169);
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.input_fld{
    margin-bottom: 17px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.input_fld > label{
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.slgn{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vh;
}

.slgn select{
    appearance:none;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #d5dbd9;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
.slgn:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    right: 10px;
    border: 8px solid;
    border-color: #d5dbd9 transparent transparent ;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  
.slgn select:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    animation: 0.8s ease;
  }

input[type="text"] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    height: 6vh;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    animation: 0.8s ease;
}
input[type="tel"] {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 5.5vh;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

input[type="email"]{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 6vh;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type="email"]:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

.input_fld textarea{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(36, 36, 36, 0.558);;
    margin: 5px auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    height: 88px;
    resize: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding:10px 13px;
}

.input_fld textarea:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}
 
input[type="checkbox"], .chckbx .fa-square-check {
    display: none;
}

.fa-square{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .fa-square-check {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .fa-square {
    display: none;
}

.chckbx i:focus {
    border: 3px solid #fec107;
    transition: 0.8s ease;
}

i {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.ttbx{
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18.8px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 74px;
}

.input_fld .btn{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 9px 11px;
    font-size: 19px; 
    border: 0px;
    background:  #6b8669;
    color: #343533;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: none;
    margin: 10px 0 auto;
  }

.input_fld:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }

  @media (max-width:520px) {
    #fmr form .input_fld{
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>This</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"/>

  <body>
    <div id="fmr">
      <div class="titl">Registration Form</div>
      <form action="info.php">
        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>First Name : </label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>Last name : </label>
          <input type="text" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label> Email Address : </label>
          <input type="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label>Gender : </label>
          <div class="slgn">
            <select name="gender" id="gender">
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="male">Male</option>
              <option value="female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label for="idc"> Phone Number:</label>
          <input type="tel" pattern="[+]{0-2}{0-12}" />
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <label for="ide"> Address : </label>
          <textarea class="address"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="input_sl">
          <label class="chckbx">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <i class="fa-regular fa-square"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-square-check"></i>

            <span class="ttbx"> Do you agree to the terms and conditions </span>
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="input_fld">
          <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please check in screen upto 520px